# Get the lowest list count in array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, stl

I have an array of lists (`array<list<Client*>, 10>`) and I want to see which list has the lowest item count in it so I can add to that. I'm doing a small balancing system here and as clients come in I want to add them to 1 or the 10 lists which has the lowest number of other clients to keep the lists level.

Would I have to do a bubble sort here or is there some sweet stl way to handle something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's precisely what [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) is for:

```
std::array<std::list<Client*>, 10> arr;

auto it = std::min_element(arr.begin(), arr.end(), 
          [](const std::list<Client*>& a, const std::list<Client*>& b){
              return a.size() < b.size();
          });
```

That'll give you an iterator into which `list` has the fewest elements.

Answer (score 5):

If the lists start at zero elements when you start adding to them and you want to keep them perfectly balanced, consider just adding to the lists round robin style:

Pseudo Code:

```
index = 0
list to add to = lists[index % list length]
index++
```

Comment: So much better than everything else. Lateral thinking > *

Comment: Yes. I approve of this style of XY-answering.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually need it sorted such that the list with the lowest item count appears first (and not `std::min_element` to simply get the lowest item like [Barry suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28488548/27678)), then you could use [std::partial_sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partial_sort/), e.g.:

```
std::array<int,10> myArray{10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
std::partial_sort(myArray.begin(),myArray.begin()+1,myArray.end(), 
   [](const int& lhs, const int& rhs){return lhs < rhs;});
```

Where the last parameter here is a lambda for comparison. You'd replace it with something like

```
[](const list<Client*>& lhs, const list<Client*>& rhs){return lhs.size() < rhs.size();)
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/aQ00lT)

Answer (score 1):

If all the clients are serviced (removed from the lists) at the same rate, then round-robin scheduling is the obvious answer.

If, however, there's variability (e.g., you're simulating customers who take different lengths of time) you probably want something like a priority queue of collections, using the length of each collection as the priority. This will place the current highest priority item (shortest list) in a known location (usually the first item in the queue). After you insert a new item, you (potentially ) "sift" that down the heap to maintain the heap property.

This allows you to insert or remove an item with O(log N) complexity, where something like `std::min_element` would require O(N) complexity.

As an aside: if you care about speed, chances are pretty good that `list` isn't a great choice either. A list has individually allocated nodes, and each node contains two pointers. These factors tend to lead to poor locality of reference, which generally implies poor cache usage. A priority_queue of vectors instead (for only one possibility) will often work better.